# JavaScript/PHP [Show/Hide]

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

What I am trying to figure out how to use JavaScript to Show/Hide PHP scripts.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(id){ 
    if (document.getElementById){ 
    obj = document.getElementById(id); 
    if (obj.style.display == "none"){ 
    obj.style.display = ""; 
    } else { 
     obj.style.display = "none"; 
    } 
  }
} 
</script>
```

Body Code:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='javascript:showhide('delivery.php');'>Show/Hide Delivery options</a>";
require "delivery.php" ?>
```

Any ideas on why/how I could get this to work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This one might take forever to figure out (because its not possible lol)

Comment: Look into AJAX/JQEURY. You can kind of get what you looking for by loading in different things through AJAX to simulate what you want to do.

Comment: Do you to show the contents of the php-file or the result of the executed php-file?

Comment: The server will read the PHP code regardless of javascript showing/hiding it.

Comment: I show the contents of the PHP file, and then pass a value from the delivery.php file

Comment: What's inside `delivery.php`?

Comment: Any good tutorials for JQUERY show/hide about?

Comment: Delivery.php contains a HTML table with 3 radio buttons.

Comment: Do you really have an id called `delivery.php`?

Comment: Okay then. I'll do away with delivery.php and keep the HTMl table in the basket.php and use Jquery for show/hide. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is Client-side, that means it is executed on your PC, after the website has been downloaded from the server.

PHP is server-side, that means it is executed on the Server computer, and then it sends a pure HTML page to your PC.

That's why its not possible. You have to use PHP to do that, using some variables. Otherwise you can use javascript/ajax to send a request to the server, which then sends the new information back to the client, which can then update the page.

But its better to just do it in PHP like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['some_var'])) {
    switch ($_GET['some_var']) {
        default: case "blah":
                 include("somefile.php"); break;
        case "nyah":
                 include("some_other_file.php"); break;
    }
}
```

'some_var' can be send to the PHP page with a form like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="some_var" value="blah"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

If you type "blah" into the text field and send it, the page will show 'somefile.php', but if you type "nyah" it will show 'some_other_file.php's contents instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is ajax (e.g. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve what you're trying to do in the way you're doing it here. As stated by @Ozzy in the comments, it is impossible.

The reason for this is that the Javascript code never knows about what the PHP code is doing. All the JS code knows about is what is received by the browser. This means that it gets the contents of the `delivery.php` file as part of the page, but does not know that it originated from a separate file to the rest of the page, let alone know what that file was called.

The quick answer is to add a wrapping `<div>` element around the `require()` statement.

This will give you an element that your Javascript code can target for the show/hide function.

So your PHP code might now look like this:

```
<?php
echo "<a href='javascript:showhide('deliveryblock');'>Show/Hide Delivery options</a>";
echo "<div id='deliveryblock'>";
require "delivery.php"
echo "</div>";
?>
```

(This does assume that the content generated by `delivery.php` is valid HTML code, but you haven't shown us what that file looks like, so I'll just have to make that assumption).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're basically trying to show/hide some content on the page. Your `showhide` function will only work for some html components on your web page. So just try to put the contents of "delivery.php" into an element like `<div id='deliverydiv'></div>`. Then use `showhide('deliverydiv')`.